# Duplicar arquivos bootstrap na pasta de adm ou apenas remanejar os caminhos?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, diretório

Desenvolvi um site, agora preciso criar um "ADM" para controlar o mesmo.

Esses são os arquivos do site principal:

[image: estrutura de pastas]

Criei uma pasta chamada `adm` no mesmo diretório que os outros arquivos e pensei em colocar todo o código do site ADM lá, porém, estou usando o Framework Bootstrap e gostaria de saber se eu coloco todos os arquivos do Bootstrap dentro dessa pasta ADM e faço tudo novamente ou se dentro desta pasta eu posso criar meu `index.php` e quando for chamar css/js. Eu apenas poderia arrumar o caminho pra pasta já existente no diretório anterior?

Se a melhor opção for remanejar os caminhos para os diretórios anteriores, eu devo criar um CSS específico para o site adm, sendo que já tenho um CSS especifico para o site chamado que é o arquivo `estilo.css`?

Comment: Não é uma resposta, é só uma observação, mas CMSs como Wordpress e o Joomla por exemplo trabalham com arquivos separados. A parte "font-end" tem sua pasta e todos seus arquivos, e uma parte para o adm trabalhar tem sua pasta e todos seus arquivos. Um ambiente não compartilha nada do outro... Aqui tem uma imagem basicona pra vc entender melhor, mas no Google vc encontra mais http://www.gobiznow.com/wordpress-tutorials/images/wp-themes-02.jpg

Comment: Era isso mesmo que precisava, obrigada.